# Aiogram на webhook и своем сервере телеграм

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram

Есть свой сервер телеграм, на этом же сервер делаю бота на aiogram, по документации и примерам с гита, но после запуска сервер ни как не реагирует на действия в боте, сервер точно рабочий, так как на telebot все работает, а на aiogram ни каких реакций, вот код

```
    TOKEN = config['TOKEN']

# Webserver settings
# bind localhost only to prevent any external access
WEB_SERVER_HOST = "127.0.0.1"
# Port for incoming request from reverse proxy. Should be any available port
WEB_SERVER_PORT = 8443

# Path to webhook route, on which Telegram will send requests
WEBHOOK_PATH = f'/webhook/{TOKEN}'
# Base URL for webhook will be used to generate webhook URL for Telegram,
# in this example it is used public DNS with HTTPS support
BASE_WEBHOOK_URL = "http://127.0.0.1/"

# All handlers should be attached to the Router (or Dispatcher)
router = Router()


@router.message(CommandStart())
async def command_start_handler(message: Message) -> None:
    """
    This handler receives messages with `/start` command
    """
    # Most event objects have aliases for API methods that can be called in events' context
    # For example if you want to answer to incoming message you can use `message.answer(...)` alias
    # and the target chat will be passed to :ref:`aiogram.methods.send_message.SendMessage`
    # method automatically or call API method directly via
    # Bot instance: `bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, ...)`
    await message.answer(f"Hello, {hbold(message.from_user.full_name)}!")


@router.message()
async def echo_handler(message: types.Message) -> None:
    """
    Handler will forward receive a message back to the sender

    By default, message handler will handle all message types (like text, photo, sticker etc.)
    """
    try:
        # Send a copy of the received message
        await message.send_copy(chat_id=message.chat.id)
    except TypeError:
        # But not all the types is supported to be copied so need to handle it
        await message.answer("Nice try!")


async def on_startup(bot: Bot) -> None:
    # If you have a self-signed SSL certificate, then you will need to send a public
    # certificate to Telegram
    await bot.set_webhook(f"{BASE_WEBHOOK_URL}{WEBHOOK_PATH}")

async def on_shutdown(bot: Bot) -> None:
    await bot.delete_webhook()

def main() -> None:
    # Dispatcher is a root router
    dp = Dispatcher()
    # ... and all other routers should be attached to Dispatcher
    dp.include_router(router)

    # Register startup hook to initialize webhook
    dp.startup.register(on_startup)
    dp.shutdown.register(on_shutdown)
    session = AiohttpSession(
        api=TelegramAPIServer.from_base('http://localhost:8081')
    )
    # Initialize Bot instance with a default parse mode which will be passed to all API calls
    bot = Bot(TOKEN, session=session)
    logging.info(bot.get_me())
    # Create aiohttp.web.Application instance
    app = web.Application()

    # Create an instance of request handler,
    # aiogram has few implementations for different cases of usage
    # In this example we use SimpleRequestHandler which is designed to handle simple cases
    webhook_requests_handler = SimpleRequestHandler(
        dispatcher=dp,
        bot=bot,
        secret_token=WEBHOOK_SECRET,
    )
    # Register webhook handler on application
    webhook_requests_handler.register(app, path=WEBHOOK_PATH)

    # Mount dispatcher startup and shutdown hooks to aiohttp application
    setup_application(app, dp, bot=bot)

    # And finally start webserver
    web.run_app(app, host=WEB_SERVER_HOST, port=WEB_SERVER_PORT)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                        handlers=[RotatingFileHandler(
                        filename="logs/logs.txt", maxBytes=1000000, backupCount=5, encoding="utf-8")],
                        format="%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s", encoding="utf-8", datefmt='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
    main()
```

что может быть не так?

Answer (score 0):

Извините, не указал порт) глупость редкостная)